# How can I do scraping on a Table in Google Sheets?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I was wondering how to get the table from the following [webpage](https://www.gob.cl/coronavirus/casosconfirmados/?fbclid=IwAR16iax-OFCsokwTjvZa8DS8QD5B6qZRVqBRDLlqH5Wqj7AGfY_Yj6p_8UY). I imagine that is possible using `importHTML` function, but it was not possible to identify the path. I think that is masked or is not accessible.

Does someone know how to get the correct path or how to import this table?
Thank you

Comment: This is obviously a dynamically created page. Use selenium or a web scraper tool or service, e.g. https://www.octoparse.com/blog/9-free-web-scrapers-that-you-cannot-miss

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GoogleSheets could handle it. As stated by @wp78de, a lot of scripts are running in the background. But you can access the data directly in JSON format here :

[Data](https://atlas.jifo.co/api/connectors/53c116ec-41cb-4560-ae21-45b3263fa73c)